# Why my validate_on_submit() doesn't work?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

After I fill out the form and click on "submit" the file is not saved. It works that the form is "Fail to submit". Spent 3 hours already and can not find the problem

main.py

```
def new_add_payment(id,summ,less,typer):
    timer = datetime.datetime.now()
    f = codecs.open(os.path.abspath('invoices') + '/' + str(id) + '$' + str(timer) + '.json', 'w', 'utf-8')
    payment = {'id': id, 'summ': summ, 'less': less, 'type': typer}
    f.write(str(payment))
```

In routes try different combinations but they don't work.

routes.py

```
@app.route('/new_payment',methods = ['GET','POST',])
def new_add_payment():
    form = AddPaymentNew()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        id = format(form.sub.data)
        summ = format(form.summ.data)
        lessons = format(form.summ.data)
        typer = request.form['options']
        main.new_add_payment(id,summ,lessons,typer)
        print('Submit successful')
        return render_template('ok.html')
    else:
        print('Fail to submit')
    return render_template('payment_new.html', title='NEW ADD PAYMENT',form=form)
```

I guess main problem is in HTML file, but i can't figure it out

payments_new.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="Generator" content="Wolf 1.42">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">

<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Actor|Lato:300|&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <title>Payment</title>

</head>
<style type=text/css>

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa&display=swap');
.new1 {font-family:'Comfortaa'}
.new2 {background-image:url(../static/ach/bg1.png)}
</style>
<body class="new2">
    <h1 class="new1" align="center">Оплата</h1>
    <form action="{{ new_add_payment }}">
        {{form.csrf_token}}
        <p class="new1" align="center">
            {{ form.sub.label }}<br>
            {{ form.sub(size=32) }}<br>
        </p>
        <p class="new1" align="center">
            {{ form.summ.label }}<br>
            {{ form.summ(size=32) }}<br>
        </p>

        <p class="new1" align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" value="1"> 1 |
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" value="2"> 2 |
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option5" value="5"> 3 |
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" value="3"> 4 |
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option4" value="4"> 5 |
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option6" value="6"> 6
        </p>
        <p class="new1" align="center">
            {{ form.lessons.label }}<br>
            {{ form.lessons(size=32) }}<br>
        </p>
        <p class = 'new1' align="center">{{form.submit()}}</p>
        <p class="new1" align="center"><a href="menu">Back</a></p>
        <p class="new1" align="center">Payments v.1.1</p>


    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Adding method = "post " to <form action="{{ new_add_payment }}"> does nothing

Comment: my form.py `class AddPaymentNew(FlaskForm):
    sub = IntegerField('ID Студента', validators=[DataRequired()])
    summ = IntegerField('Сумма Оплаты', validators=[DataRequired()])
    lessons = IntegerField('Количество уроков', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Добавить', validators=[DataRequired()])`

Answer (score 0):

There just isn't enough information here - you don't show your form definition. Why don't you print out the contents of the form (or use a debugger) prior to calling submit to make sure that your routes are working, and the data you are getting is what you think.

With your additional info - your submit button shouldn't have any validators (as it doesn't transmit any data).
Also - form.errors has a list of all errors encountered - by field - I would print that out.

Comment: I already do it. Path that program takes is always ends on fail to validate

Answer (score 0):

to check precisely where your validation fails you can add this chunk of code in your template to make the debugging process easily

```
{% for error in form.errors %}

    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
    <p><i class="icon fas fa-ban"></i> Alert!</p>
        {{ error }} invalid
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

besides that, your form doesn't have a method assigned to

```
<form action="/controller_method/" method="post">
```